# Script's execution "scope" - Google Forms - Managing Triggers Programmatically

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

My script works as displayed in "[Google I-O 2013 - Use Apps Script to Create Dynamic Google Forms](https://developers.google.com/events/io/sessions/327782631)". In that video Teacher dynamically generates (via Forms) another Form to submit to her students.

I created a Form programmatically, and I attached a function to, handled by a trigger (OnSubmit) that sends an email.

All works fine, but when functions runs it (seems) to run into "parent" context. In fact if I use getActiveForm functions, I get parent context instead current one.

Could anyone help me?

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by "parent context", could you please elaborate on that?

Comment: If I understand correctly what is happening here, we are seeing "correct" behaviour. Indeed you are creating a Form B from Form A. The onSubmitFunction() that you are adding to the trigger is contained in form A even though you are attaching it to a trigger which execute on Form B. When onSubmit fires, your onSubmitFunction() runs, but it runs as part of the original Form A where is lies. Its an interesting problem indeed :) what do you need to do in your onSubmitFunction() that requires you to have child form scope that you can not do from the event parameters?